# Java code hangs at Scanner hasNextLine

Tags: java, block

First off, I'm new to java and trying to complete an assignment from school on creating a vending machine. My program is taking in 2 files as cli arguments, one for products, and the other for money.

For the life of me I cannot figure out why the code is hanging on line 42

```
 (while (moneyTemp.hasNextLine());)
```

I tried to debug on eclipse using breakpoints and noticed the code never goes past this line. Putting a print statement inside the while loop, i don't get the output so i know it is not looping.

The java docs say hasNextLine can block waiting for user input, but since my source is a file, I'm not sure why this is happening. See relevant code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class VendingMachine
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner productTempFile = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            Scanner moneyTemp = new Scanner(new File(args[1]));
            int numProducts = 0; //Number of products to be loaded to the machines
            int numMoney = 0;   //Number of money objects to be loaded in the machine

            while (productTempFile.hasNextLine()) //This block will get the number of products
            {
                numProducts++;
                productTempFile.nextLine();
            }
            productTempFile.close();


            Product[] invArray = new Product[numProducts];
            Scanner myFile = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

            for(int i = 0; i < numProducts; i++)  //This block populates the array of products
            {
                String inputLine = myFile.nextLine();                               
                String[] lineArray = inputLine.split(",");

                invArray[i] = new Product(lineArray[0], Double.valueOf(lineArray[1]), lineArray[2], lineArray[3],
                        Double.valueOf(lineArray[4]), Integer.valueOf(lineArray[5]));
            } 

            myFile.close();

            System.out.println("I'm here");

            while (moneyTemp.hasNextLine()); //This block gets the number of different money items
            {
                numMoney++;
                moneyTemp.nextLine();               
            }
```

Below is the second file i am supplying ie arg[1] which is formatted same like first one which works.

```
PaperCurrency,100 Dollar Bill,100.0,medium,paper,0
PaperCurrency,50 Dollar Bill,50.0,medium,paper,0
PaperCurrency,20 Dollar Bill,20.0,medium,paper,0
PaperCurrency,10 Dollar Bill,10.0,medium,paper,4
PaperCurrency,5 Dollar Bill,5.0,medium,paper,8
PaperCurrency,1 Dollar Bill,100.0,medium,paper,16
CoinCurrency,50 Cent Piece,0.5,large,metal,10
CoinCurrency,Quarter,0.25,medium,metal,20
CoinCurrency,Dime,0.1,small,metal,30
CoinCurrency,Nickel,0.05,small,metal,40
CoinCurrency,Penny,0.01,small,metal,50
```

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove semicolon from the line

```
 while (moneyTemp.hasNextLine());
```

Semicolom make the while loop complete its body without doing anything means its like `while(){}` when while condition is true do nothing and since your condition is `hasNextLine()` it checks for same line again and again causing infinite loop.

Comment: Ah, the old semicolon at the end of a while...I've been frustrated by that before.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I can't believe it's something as small as this :) I was thinking it would be something so much advanced. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the semicolon (`;`), you are implicitly having the `while` loop execute an empty block. `hasNextLine()` doesn't doesn't change the `InputStream` the scanner is based on, so since there's nothing in the `while` loop's body, there's nothing to change the state, and the loop will just continue forever.

Just drop the semicolon from the `while` loop, and you should be fine:

```
while (moneyTemp.hasNextLine()) // no ; here!
{
    numMoney++;
    moneyTemp.nextLine();               
}
```

Comment: How this answer is different from the other one?